# ProjectEuler's distinct prime factors of a given number

Tags: java

folks, I've been struggling to figure out the algorithm to get the list of all of the prime factors of the given number (in my case, the given number is `myNumber = 14`). For example,

```
    14 = 2 × 7
    15 = 3 × 5
    645 = 3 × 5 × 43
    646 = 2 × 17 × 19
```

But my code is running infinitely and I'm not pretty sure if my algorithm works fine. Could smb take a look or give me a hand how to see the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
public class DistinctFactors {

    public static final List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int result = 1;
        int myNumber = 14;

        int i = 2;

        while(result != myNumber){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                myList.add(i);
                result *= i;
            }
            i++;
        }

        for(int j = 0; i < myList.size(); j++){
            System.out.print(myList.get(j) + " ");
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int number){
        for(int i = 2; i < number; i++){
            if(number % 2 == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this really isn't in the spirit of ProjectEuler but look at the logic of your main loop. You're multiplying `result` by every prime number. You'll want to only use primes that divide `myNumber`

Comment: @DavidM, but that's what I need to do. I need get the list of all the prime numbers such that if you multiply them altogether, the result would be the given number.

Comment: Yes. But take a close look at your loop. The first time through, `i=2` and is prime so you add 2 to `myList` and multiply `result` by 2. Which is fine, because 2 divides 14. Now the next iteration, `i=3` and 3 is prime. So you add 3 to `myList` and multiply `result` be 3. But 3 doesn't divide 14 so that's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, let's look at what the values of result and i will be.

```
Pass 1: r = 1, i = 2
Pass 2: r = 2, i = 3
Pass 3: r = 6, i = 4
Pass 4: r = 6, i = 5
Pass 5: r = 30, i = 6
```

From this point on, r will only increase, and it's already greater than 14. So of course this loop will never terminate.

Your method is also extremely wrong. I have no idea why you chose this way to try and get prime factors.

Not to mention, even your isPrime method is kind of dumb. It checks all the way up to the number you're checking, which is extremely wasteful.

To check if a number n is prime, you should instead compute the square root; if it is an integer, then the number is obviously not prime. Otherwise, take the floor of that sqrt(n) - let's call it k - and run the loop up to k. If n is not prime, you will find a divisor in that range; if you find none, n is prime.

(That is an O(log(n)) method. The best method is the one that involves checking whether the number satisfies [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for random values, which is constant time).

EDIT: Well, not exactly constant time if you don't consider certain operations O(1). For huge numbers it's much better than the other method

Your current loop just checks whether the number is even a bunch of times...